# Match pandas index to any row values in another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to retrieve the rows of `mrna_kirp` where its index matches any of the values anywhere in the `gmt_c4` dataframe.

```
mrna_subset = mrna_kirp.loc[mrna_kirp.index.isin(gmt_c4)]
```

As per the [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), my code only returns matches where both the index and column labels match. But I want to retrieve all possible matches.

Input:

`gmt_c4.iloc[0:5,0:5]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'MORF_ATRX': {('MORF_BCL2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2',
   'ADCY3',
   'SYT5',
   'LTBP4',
   'A1BG',
   'AQP5',
   'AQP7'): 'TMEM11',
  ('MORF_BNIP1',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1',
   'PVR',
   'ADCY3',
   'BMP10',
   'NRTN',
   'S100A5',
   'IL16'): 'SYT5',
  ('MORF_BCL2L11',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11',
   'LORICRIN',
   'PVR',
   'A2BP1',
   'FGF18',
   'BMP10',
   'F2RL3'): 'NRTN',
  ('MORF_CCNF',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF',
   'A1CF',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'EEF1AKMT3',
   'PEX3',
   'HMGN4'): 'GTSE1',
  ('MORF_ERCC2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2',
   'SEC31A',
   'BTD',
   'GRIK5',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'BPHL'): 'HNRNPL'},
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ATRX': {('MORF_BCL2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2',
   'ADCY3',
   'SYT5',
   'LTBP4',
   'UTRN',
   'AQP5',
   'AQP7'): 'KIFC3',
  ('MORF_BNIP1',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1',
   'PVR',
   'ADCY3',
   'BMP10',
   'NRTN',
   'S100A5',
   'IL16'): 'LTBP4',
  ('MORF_BCL2L11',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11',
   'LORICRIN',
   'PVR',
   'KLRC4',
   'FGF18',
   'BMP10',
   'F2RL3'): 'S100A5',
  ('MORF_CCNF',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF',
   'BMS1',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'EEF1AKMT3',
   'PEX3',
   'HMGN4'): 'HNRNPL',
  ('MORF_ERCC2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2',
   'SEC31A',
   'BTD',
   'GRIK5',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'BPHL'): 'MUTYH'},
 'ADCY3': {('MORF_BCL2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2',
   'ADCY3',
   'SYT5',
   'LTBP4',
   'UTRN',
   'AQP5',
   'AQP7'): 'HTR1B',
  ('MORF_BNIP1',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1',
   'PVR',
   'ADCY3',
   'BMP10',
   'NRTN',
   'S100A5',
   'IL16'): 'FIG4',
  ('MORF_BCL2L11',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11',
   'LORICRIN',
   'PVR',
   'KLRC4',
   'FGF18',
   'BMP10',
   'F2RL3'): 'IL16',
  ('MORF_CCNF',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF',
   'BMS1',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'EEF1AKMT3',
   'PEX3',
   'HMGN4'): 'PLEKHB1',
  ('MORF_ERCC2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2',
   'SEC31A',
   'BTD',
   'GRIK5',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'BPHL'): 'TAF5L'},
 'SEC31A': {('MORF_BCL2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2',
   'ADCY3',
   'SYT5',
   'LTBP4',
   'UTRN',
   'AQP5',
   'AQP7'): 'DDX11',
  ('MORF_BNIP1',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1',
   'PVR',
   'ADCY3',
   'BMP10',
   'NRTN',
   'S100A5',
   'IL16'): 'CYP2D6',
  ('MORF_BCL2L11',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11',
   'LORICRIN',
   'PVR',
   'KLRC4',
   'FGF18',
   'BMP10',
   'F2RL3'): 'SLC6A2',
  ('MORF_CCNF',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF',
   'BMS1',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'EEF1AKMT3',
   'PEX3',
   'HMGN4'): 'PIGF',
  ('MORF_ERCC2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2',
   'SEC31A',
   'BTD',
   'GRIK5',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'BPHL'): 'AGPS'},
 'BTD': {('MORF_BCL2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2',
   'ADCY3',
   'SYT5',
   'LTBP4',
   'UTRN',
   'AQP5',
   'AQP7'): 'AGPS',
  ('MORF_BNIP1',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1',
   'PVR',
   'ADCY3',
   'BMP10',
   'NRTN',
   'S100A5',
   'IL16'): 'GRIK5',
  ('MORF_BCL2L11',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11',
   'LORICRIN',
   'PVR',
   'KLRC4',
   'FGF18',
   'BMP10',
   'F2RL3'): 'MASP2',
  ('MORF_CCNF',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF',
   'BMS1',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'EEF1AKMT3',
   'PEX3',
   'HMGN4'): 'TPP2',
  ('MORF_ERCC2',
   'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2',
   'SEC31A',
   'BTD',
   'GRIK5',
   'EIF5B',
   'TMEM11',
   'BPHL'): 'SFSWAP'}})
```

`mrna_kirp.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': {'A1BG': 391.94,
  'A1CF': 8.0,
  'A2BP1': 1.0,
  'A2LD1': 159.46},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': {'A1BG': 68.91,
  'A1CF': 75.0,
  'A2BP1': 0.0,
  'A2LD1': 247.06},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': {'A1BG': 71.9,
  'A1CF': 28.0,
  'A2BP1': 33.0,
  'A2LD1': 516.7},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': {'A1BG': 325.6,
  'A1CF': 47.0,
  'A2BP1': 4.0,
  'A2LD1': 151.49}})
```

Desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': {'A1BG': 391.94,
  'A1CF': 8.0,
  'A2BP1': 1.0},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': {'A1BG': 68.91,
  'A1CF': 75.0,
  'A2BP1': 0.0},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': {'A1BG': 71.9,
  'A1CF': 28.0,
  'A2BP1': 33.0},
 'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': {'A1BG': 325.6,
  'A1CF': 47.0,
  'A2BP1': 4.0}})
```

Comment: How did you build `gmt_c4` dataframe? From a file? If yes, I think you should use something like `pd.read_csv(..., header=None)` to avoid to set one record as column name (it works also for `pd.read_excel` )

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset your index then convert your dataframe to a flatten numpy array and finally check if the index is in the array:

```
m = mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.hstack([gmt_c4.columns.values, gmt_c4.reset_index().values.ravel()]))
out = mrna_kirp[m]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
       TCGA.2K.A9WE.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01
A1BG            391.94            68.91             71.9            325.6
A1CF              8.00            75.00             28.0             47.0
A2BP1             1.00             0.00             33.0              4.0

>>> m
array([ True,  True,  True, False])
```

Performance:

```
# @jezrael solution 1:
>>> %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()))]
2.49 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @jezrael solution 2:
>>> %timeit mrna_kirp.loc[mrna_kirp.index.intersection(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()), sort=False)]
2.52 ms ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @Corralien
>>> %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.hstack([gmt_c4.columns.values, gmt_c4.reset_index().values.ravel()]))]
1.62 ms ± 50.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Solutions with `stack` are slower than using `.values.flatten()`.

**Note**: However, instead of check the values in column names, maybe you should modify how you load the `gmt_c4` dataframe. It seems column names are a data record? If you use a CSV/Excel file, use `header=None` as parameter of `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_excel`.

Comment: @jezrael. Yes it is now.

Answer (score 1):

For match by any value from `MultiIndex`, `columns` and `values` of `gmt_c4` use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()))]
print (out)
       TCGA.2K.A9WE.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01
A1BG            391.94            68.91             71.9            325.6
A1CF              8.00            75.00             28.0             47.0
A2BP1             1.00             0.00             33.0              4.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()))
['A1BG' 'A1CF' 'A2BP1' 'ADCY3' 'AGPS' 'AQP5' 'AQP7' 'BMP10' 'BMS1' 'BPHL'
 'BTD' 'CYP2D6' 'DDX11' 'EEF1AKMT3' 'EIF5B' 'F2RL3' 'FGF18' 'FIG4' 'GRIK5'
 'GTSE1' 'HMGN4' 'HNRNPL' 'HTR1B' 'IL16' 'KIFC3' 'KLRC4' 'LORICRIN'
 'LTBP4' 'MASP2' 'MORF_ATRX' 'MORF_BCL2' 'MORF_BCL2L11' 'MORF_BNIP1'
 'MORF_CCNF' 'MORF_ERCC2' 'MUTYH' 'NRTN' 'PEX3' 'PIGF' 'PLEKHB1' 'PVR'
 'S100A5' 'SEC31A' 'SFSWAP' 'SLC6A2' 'SYT5' 'TAF5L' 'TMEM11' 'TPP2' 'UTRN'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ATRX'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF'
 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2']
```

Similar idea with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
out = mrna_kirp.loc[mrna_kirp.index.intersection(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()), sort=False)]
print (out)
       TCGA.2K.A9WE.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01  TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01
A1BG            391.94            68.91             71.9            325.6
A1CF              8.00            75.00             28.0             47.0
A2BP1             1.00             0.00             33.0              4.0
```

For improve performance use:

```
vals = np.append(np.ravel(gmt_c4.reset_index()), gmt_c4.columns).astype(str)
out = mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(vals)]
```

Another idea with sets:

```
vals = set(np.ravel(gmt_c4.reset_index())).union(gmt_c4.columns)
out = mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(vals)]
```

For completeness performance in your data (in real shoud be different):

```
In [29]: %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()))]
3.1 ms ± 95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [30]: %timeit mrna_kirp.loc[mrna_kirp.index.intersection(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index()), sort=False)]
3.41 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.append(np.ravel(gmt_c4.reset_index()), gmt_c4.columns).astype(str))]
2.08 ms ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(set(np.ravel(gmt_c4.reset_index())).union(gmt_c4.columns))]
2.05 ms ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#Corralien solution
In [33]: %timeit mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.hstack([gmt_c4.columns.values, gmt_c4.reset_index().values.ravel()]))]
2.08 ms ± 73.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: A nicer approach!

Comment: It raises `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @melolili - can you  try `out = mrna_kirp[mrna_kirp.index.isin(np.unique(gmt_c4.stack().reset_index().astype(str)))]`  ?

Comment: @jezrael. You just replace `.values.flatten()` by `stack()`. Well done........ Your solution is almost twice slower than mine. `stack` is slow.

Comment: @Corralien - Your solution not use columns names. So is different. Added 3rd solution, I think faster.

Comment: Please try to copy correctly my solution. Can you explain me how did you get your result? https://i.stack.imgur.com/omC2C.png. Maybe you run another process to evaluate solution from other users or you modify manually the result?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Now correct.

Comment: @Corralien - why I should manually moodify it? https://snipboard.io/yT4kcz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

THe following code should work -

```
mrna_kirp.apply(lambda x: x if np.isin(x.name, np.array(list(map(list, gmt_c4.index.values)))) else None, axis=1).dropna()
```

I have broken up the code in small parts to try and make more sense of how I developed this.

```
np.array(list(map(list, gmt_c4.index.values))))
```

This line helps to convert an array of tuples to an ndarray. Accessing a multi-index returns an array of tuples. By default, the multi-index is like this -

```
array([('MORF_BCL2', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2', 'ADCY3', 'SYT5', 'LTBP4', 'A1BG', 'AQP5', 'AQP7'),
       ('MORF_BNIP1', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BNIP1', 'PVR', 'ADCY3', 'BMP10', 'NRTN', 'S100A5', 'IL16'),
       ('MORF_BCL2L11', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11', 'LORICRIN', 'PVR', 'A2BP1', 'FGF18', 'BMP10', 'F2RL3'),
       ('MORF_CCNF', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF', 'A1CF', 'EIF5B', 'TMEM11', 'EEF1AKMT3', 'PEX3', 'HMGN4'),
       ('MORF_ERCC2', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_ERCC2', 'SEC31A', 'BTD', 'GRIK5', 'EIF5B', 'TMEM11', 'BPHL'),
       ('MORF_BCL2', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2', 'ADCY3', 'SYT5', 'LTBP4', 'UTRN', 'AQP5', 'AQP7'),
       ('MORF_BCL2L11', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_BCL2L11', 'LORICRIN', 'PVR', 'KLRC4', 'FGF18', 'BMP10', 'F2RL3'),
       ('MORF_CCNF', 'http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/MORF_CCNF', 'BMS1', 'EIF5B', 'TMEM11', 'EEF1AKMT3', 'PEX3', 'HMGN4')],
      dtype=object)
```

I need to use [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to check if the index extracted from *mrna_kirp* is present as a value inside the tuple or not. np.isin cannot do what we want in the array of tuples so we convert it in the right format.

We use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to iterate through the *mrna_kirp* dataframe and retrieve each rows index using *row.name* and setting the *axis=1* for that purpose.

Lastly, we use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove the None values when the index of a row of *mrna_kirp* is not found in *gmt_c4*.